# Result of addition of two bytes when it cross its limit

Tags: c#

let i have got two byte variable:

```
byte a= 255;
byte b= 121;

byte c= (byte) (a + b);

Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

output:120

please explain me how this is adding values. i know that its crossing size limit of byte but don't know what exactly operation it performs in such situation because its not looking like its chopping the result.

Thanks

EDIT: sorry its 120 as a answer.

Comment: That is unusual. I would have expected `120` as the output.

Comment: Your sample does not compile. Did you mean `byte c = (byte) (a + b)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What actually happens when a Byte overflows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156967/what-actually-happens-when-a-byte-overflows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overflowing the byte storage of 255 so it starts from 0.

So: a + b is an integer = 376

Your code is equivalent to:

```
byte c = (byte)376;
```

That's one of the reasons why adding two bytes returns an integer. Casting it back to a byte should be done at your own risk.

If you want to store the integer 376 into bytes you need an array:

```
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(376);
```

As you can see the resulting array contains 4 bytes now which is what is necessary to store a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 5):

It gets obvious when you look at the binary representation of the values:

```
var | decimal | binary
----|----------------------
  a |     255 |   1111 1111
  b |     121 |   0111 1001
    |         |
a+b |     376 | 1 0111 1000
```

This gets truncated to 8 bits, the overflow bit is disregarded when casting the result to `byte`:

```
  c |         |   0111 1000 => 120
```

Answer (score 1):

As others are saying, you are overflowing; the `a+b` operation results in an int, which you are explicitly casting to a byte.  Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691289%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), essentially in an unchecked context, the cast is done by truncating the most significant bits.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `byte c= (byte)(a + b);`

On my end the result here is 120, and that is what I would expect.

a+b equals 376, and all bits that represent 256 and up gets stripped (since `byte` actually only hold 1 byte), then 120 is what you are left with inside your byte.