# Byte conversion in c#

Tags: c#

Does not get correct result using this code. After inserting 300 as int, I am getting 44 as the converted byte value.

I was expecting 255 as this is the closest to 300.

```
Console.Write("Enter int value - ");
val1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// converting int to byte
bval1 =  (byte) val1;
Console.WriteLine("int explicit conversion");
Console.WriteLine("byte - {0}", bval1);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're expecting. Since `300` doesn't fit in `byte`, obviously you won't get `300`, but what were you hoping for instead of `44`?

Comment: Why is 255 the expected result?

Comment: It seems you imagine that datatypes have a certain capacity and overflowing them just means that you will be stuck at full capacity? It doesn't work like that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just experienced [byte overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156967/what-actually-happens-when-a-byte-overflows). Try to use types that can actually hold the numbers that you work with.

**[edit]**

It looks that conversion can be also [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s682k58(v=vs.90).aspx) in C#:

```
bval1 =  checked ((byte) val1);
```

and have the appropriate exception (`OverflowException`) when value is too big

Answer (score 6):

A single unsigned byte can hold a range of 0 to 255.  or 0x00 to 0xff.  300 is greater than 256 so it "wraps around" or begins counting again from 0.  300 - 44 = 256, that's your wrap.