# When the int variable is more than 10 digits

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the int variable is more than 10 digits, an error occurs and the number becomes negative.

Why is this happening and how can I solve the problem?

This is my code:

```
UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar");
www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
JSONNode itemsData = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);
unixtimeOnline = itemsData2["lastUpdated"];
Debug.Log(unixtimeOnline);
    // output -2147483648
```

Comment: `int` has a limited range (max 2,147,483,647). Can you use `long` instead? See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know why there is a limit for the boxes?

Comment: The limit for `int` is  2,147,483,647, so when you try and put a higher value into it Bad Things™️ happen. For instance, when you add 1 to that max value, you get -2,147,483,648. There just isn't enough space in a 32-bit number to store higher values

Comment: @Lelouchkun what "boxes"?

Comment: since the time is probably never negative you could also just use `uint`, `ulong` which would give you wider ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Simply use `ulong` instead of `int` for `unixtimeOnline`

```
ulong unixtimeOnline = itemsData2["lastUpdated"];
```

---

#### What happened?

As was already mentioned `int` (or also `System.Int32`) has **32** bits.

The [`int.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-6.0) is

```
2147483647
```

no `int` can be higher than that. What you get is basically a [byte overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156967/what-actually-happens-when-a-byte-overflows).

From the `JSON.Parse` I suspect you are using [`SimpleJson`](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON/blob/master/SimpleJSON.cs)

and if you have

```
int unixtimeOnline = itemsData2["lastUpdated"];
```

it will implicitly use

> ```
> public static implicit operator int(JSONNode d)
> {
>     return (d == null) ? 0 : d.AsInt;
> }
> ```

which uses [`AsInt`](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON/blob/ac13597cb66536d08f89b3441bff6624564608cf/SimpleJSON.cs#L286)

> ```
>  public virtual int AsInt
>  {
>      get { return (int)AsDouble; }
>      set { AsDouble = value; }
>  }
> ```

which is a problem because a `double` can hold up to

so when you simply do

```
double d = 2147483648.0;
int example = (int)d;
```

you will again get

```
-2147483648
```

---

#### What you want

You want to use a type that supports larger numbers. Like e.g.

- `long`: goes up to

  ```
  9,223,372,036,854,775,807
  ```

  and is actually what system time ticks are usually stored as (see e.g. [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks)

or actually since your time is probably never negative anyway directly use the unsigned ones

- `ulong`: goes up to

  ```
  18,446,744,073,709,551,615
  ```

---

#### Solution

Long store short: There are implicit conversion for the other numeric values so all you need to do is use

```
ulong unixtimeOnline = itemsData2["lastUpdated"];
```

and it will use `AsUlong` instead

> ```
> public static implicit operator ulong(JSONNode d)
> {
>     return (d == null) ? 0 : d.AsULong;
> }
> ```

which now correctly uses

> ```
>  public virtual ulong AsULong
>  {
>      get
>      {
>          ulong val = 0;
>          if (ulong.TryParse(Value, out val))
>              return val;
>          return 0;
>      }
>      set
>      {
>          Value = value.ToString();
>      }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says you will need to use a `long` variable type